# Cannot access to folder outside a container

Tags: c#, docker, ubuntu, puppeteer-sharp

I wrote an application in C# which need to use a browser instance like chrome. I dockerized the application and the run using:

```
sudo docker run -d --name myapp --restart=always -e BROWSER_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser myimage
```

The application start correctly but I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to launch browser! path to executable does not exist) ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Failed to launch browser! path to executable does not exist

seems that the `Docker` container cannot access to the browser folder which is located outside of the container.

I'm using `puppeteer-sharp` to manage the browser, so the lines which is throwing the error is the folling:

```
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
     Headless = true,
     ExecutablePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BROWSER_PATH"),
});
```

as you can see I'm reading the `BROWSER_PATH` from an environment variable.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to mount the volume as suggested using:

```
sudo docker run -d --name myapp --restart=always -e BROWSER_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --v "/$(pwd)/usr/bin/chromium-browser:/usr/bin/chromium-browser" myimage
```

but I get the same error:

> Failed to launch browser! path to executable does not exist

what I did wrong?

Comment: Containers don't see host files by default, you must explicitly mount them inside. See here https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: For this reason it's called container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mount them in container.
https://flaviocopes.com/docker-access-files-outside-container/

Comment: Can you add here how to do that so your Answer is more complete, please?

Comment: @Scratte I did this but I have the same problem, could you check my update?

Comment: @sfarzoso I do not know about C# or docker. So I cannot help you. I just noticed this answer looking like it could benefit with more information.

Comment: @sfarzoso you have put two dashes before 'v'. If that didn't help, try to debug this by using container's shell. Use this command to exec into the container: `sudo docker run -it --rm -e BROWSER_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser -v "/$(pwd)/usr/bin/chromium-browser:/usr/bin/chromium-browser" myimage sh`. When you inside you can inspect why this isn't working.

Comment: @anemyte seems that the solution proposed is working 'cause I can see the directory mounted, but the problem is that `Docker` creates a directory called `chromium-browser` instead of takes the binary from `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`. Is there a way to tell to `Docker` that `chromium-browser` is not a directory but a binary of `Ubuntu` package?